# how to execute a shell script when an ebtables rules match?

Tags: shell, iptables, ebtables

I want to execute a shell script when particular ebtables rules match. The Script should get the MAC address of the client and the interface in which the client is connected. how can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. One option is to log the packets then you can execute a command from Syslog (with a pipe for example).

Example:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -s 00:11:22:33:44:55 --log --log-prefix " EBTABLES "
```

That rule will match all the packets with the source mac address 00:11:22:33:44:55 and the string EBTABLES should appear in syslog. You should have care with this, because it sould be a little agressive if you have to much traffic.